# kryo Encountered unregistered class ID, even though I've registered all classes

Tags: java, scala, serialization, deserialization, kryo

I have a spark job that serializes an object with setRegistrationRequired(true).
I have added registrations for all the classes.
I have java code that deserializes the serialized object, also with setRegistrationRequired(true) and all appropriate registrations, making sure that the order of registrations is the same.

While deserializing, I get `com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Encountered unregistered class ID: 113`

At first, I thought I was missing some class, but then realized if that was the case, I wouldn't be able to serialize the object in the first place, since `requiredRegistration` is set to `true`.

so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: does it work with only one node ? do you have custom serializer?

Comment: Im doing testing only on one machine, but different jvm. no, im not using custom serializer.

Comment: Does it work when you do not register classes at all and setRegistrationRequired(false) ? apart from that, its hard to debug code you can't see ;-)